# WCF Serice - Getting 400 Bad Request but can use IE to browse to it

Tags: c#, wcf

I have written a WCF Service which is being called by a Winforms application.

I have tested calling the WCF Service from the WinForms application locally and it all works fine

I have moved both the WinForms application and the WCF Service to a Remote Server, on the Remote Server I can use IE to browse to the Service but when I try to use the Winforms application I get a 400 Bad Response error.

My local machine and the Remote Server has been configured exactly the same, Windows Firewall, User accounts etc and the codebase/config files of both the Service and Winforms app are the same.

The config file for the WCF Service is as follows (i've had to remove the base address)

```
<bindings>

  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webBinding">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>

</bindings>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="CodeLocksAPIServiceBehavior" name="CodeLocksAPI.WCF.CodeLocksAPIService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="CodeLocksAPI.WCF.ICodeLocksAPIService" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CodeLocksAPIServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

In the Winforms app config I have tried adding the DefaultProxy tabs which do not help

WCF Service is called from Code Using the following

```
string serviceUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceUserName"];
string servicePassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServicePassword"];

HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Credentials = new
             System.Net.NetworkCredential(serviceUserName, servicePassword)
};

this.Client = new HttpClient(handler);
this.Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(this.GetBaseAddressFromConfig());
processInitializeLockRequestArgs.AssetRef = assetRef;

string contentMessage = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(processInitializeLockRequestArgs);
byte[] contentBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contentMessage);

ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(contentBytes);
content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

httpResponse = this.Client.PostAsync(methodUri, content).Result;
```

As already stated - this code is working locally but not on the remote server - the WCF Service can be browsed to locally and on the remote service

I've been informed that the issue is most likely down to Proxy settings on the WinForms application and that the issue is not down to a Firewall or anything like that

Comment: You are trying to pass credentials along with your request whereas in the configuration clientCredentialType is None. Can you trying not passing handler in HttpClient?

Comment: Other ways is to try changing the configuration to windows and leave your code as is  <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>

Comment: I can't use TLS security as its only an internal call so running it over HTTP not HTTPS

Comment: Then you can set httpsGetEnabled to false

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
  </system.net>
....
```

to the beginning of your WinForms config file.

Comment: thanks but already tried it, tried adding that on its own and this  <system.net>
 <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy usesystemdefault="False" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>

neither were successful

Comment: Fair enough! Proxies aren't my specialist subject but this one's sorted me out a couple of times! :-)